# Finding number of relatives from connections

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

I am trying to find the number of relatives a person has, including their extended family, from a list of connections.

For example:

- relative: A, B
- relative: A, C
- colleague: D, A
- colleague: E, B
- relative: B, E
- relative: C, B

Relative A should have a total of 4 relatives (B, C, E via B, and himself).

Here's what I've attempted so far, It doesn't work for further relatives and for themselves:

```
public static int relatives(Person person) {
    int relatives = 0;

    ArrayList<Relationships> relationships = getRelations();

    for (int i = 0; i < relationships.size(); i++) {
        if (relationships.get(i).getPerson1().getName().equals(person.getName())) {
            if (relationships.get(i).getType().equals("relative")) {
                relatives++;
            }
        }
    }
    return relationships;
}
```

The `getRelations()` method just reads a text file containing the list of relations as I posted above and puts them into a `Relationships` object.

The `Relationships` class holds 2 people and the type of relationship.

Comment: getType() won't return what your expecting, unless you  you'll need to create a method to do what you want it to it will return Type Relationship from the look of it so far, or if you have overriden it

Comment: You should implement either [depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [disjoint sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)

Comment: @tobias_k I havent heard/use those, how would I go about implementing that?

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/